# Проверка, что через 3 вектора можно провести ровную линию

Tags: геометрия, lua, scripts

Как можно определить/проверять, что через (допустим) 3 вектора можно провести ровную линию для использования способности на врагов.

Вот у меня есть 3 вражеских героя к примеру. Позиции каждого я могу получить Vector(x, y, z).
[image]

Вот как это выглядит, если получить позицию одного врага
[image]

Дальше мне нужно рассчитать, стоят ли враги в линию, для того, что бы использовать ультимативную способность.
[image]

Хотелось бы добавить, что если делать самому, т.е. мышкой навестись на определенную точку, то ее можно крутить по кругу. Сам центр, куда я ее зажал меняться не будет, но ее крайние точки -- да
[image]

Используется сама способность. Как можно видеть это стенка, координаты которой я тоже могу получить
[image]

Как я понимаю, для того, что бы поставить стенку и она задевала всех героев, я должен для начала рассчитать, а возможно ли это и стоят ли враги в линию. Как мне это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имея три точки P1, P2, P3, получаете два вектора

```
V1 = P2 - P1
V2 = P3 - P1
```

И считаете их векторное произведение (в 2D - кросс-продукт)

```
A = V1 x V2 = V1.X * V2.Y - V1.Y * V2.X
```

Для того, чтобы избавиться от погрешностей (надо полагать, что в ваших условиях маленький угол - всё равно, что нулевой), нормируйте на характерный размер

```
R = max(abs(V1.X), abs(V2.X), abs(V1.Y), abs(V2.Y))
```

И сравнение выполняйте

```
if (abs(A) < R * R * Eps)
    значит - на одной прямой
```

где Eps - малая величина - например, 0.01 или 0.000001 - смотря как в вашей задаче требуется.

Comment: В чем смысл получения 2-ух векторов, если я и так их получаю? Т.е. перебирая героев во круг, в определенном радиусе, я получаю вектора героев (если они есть конечно)

Comment: Вы путаете геометрические векторы и точки. У вас точки, позиции. Разности между ними - векторы.